# How to use bignumbers in truffle tests?

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, bignumber

I am testing a smartcontract with Truffle V5. All works well if I do not use all decimals. If I set 18 decimals all explodes. The test code is this (from truffle docs):

```
const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");

contract("2nd MetaCoin test", async accounts => {
  it("should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account", async () => {
    let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed();
    let balance = await instance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
    assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 10000);
  });

  it("should call a function that depends on a linked library", async () => {
    let meta = await MetaCoin.deployed();
    let outCoinBalance = await meta.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
    let metaCoinBalance = outCoinBalance.toNumber();
    let outCoinBalanceEth = await meta.getBalanceInEth.call(accounts[0]);
    let metaCoinEthBalance = outCoinBalanceEth.toNumber();
    assert.equal(metaCoinEthBalance, 2 * metaCoinBalance);
  });

  it("should send coin correctly", async () => {
    // Get initial balances of first and second account.
    let account_one = accounts[0];
    let account_two = accounts[1];

    let amount = 10;

    let instance = await MetaCoin.deployed();
    let meta = instance;

    let balance = await meta.getBalance.call(account_one);
    let account_one_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();

    balance = await meta.getBalance.call(account_two);
    let account_two_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
    await meta.sendCoin(account_two, amount, { from: account_one });

    balance = await meta.getBalance.call(account_one);
    let account_one_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();

    balance = await meta.getBalance.call(account_two);
    let account_two_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();

    assert.equal(
      account_one_ending_balance,
      account_one_starting_balance - amount,
      "Amount wasn't correctly taken from the sender"
    );
    assert.equal(
      account_two_ending_balance,
      account_two_starting_balance + amount,
      "Amount wasn't correctly sent to the receiver"
    );
  });
});
```

This is the smart contract I need to test (from MetaCoin.sol file, modified on order to use latest compiler (currently I use 0.5.2) and etc.). The original can be found [here](https://github.com/truffle-box/metacoin-box/blob/master/contracts/MetaCoin.sol):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

// This is just a simple example of a coin-like contract.
// It is not standards compatible and cannot be expected to talk to other
// coin/token contracts. If you want to create a standards-compliant
// token, see: https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens. Cheers!

contract MetaCoin {

// I add this section in EIP20 style
    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint _totalSupply

    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor() public {

// I modified constructor to introduce symbol, name, decimals and totalSupply
        symbol = "MTC";
        name = "MetaCoin Example Token";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 10000 * 10**uint(decimals);  
        balances[tx.origin] = _totalSupply;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) public view returns(uint){
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}
```

All is ok if decimals is, for instace "1" or "2", but when I use "18" i loose the control. How can I implement bignumbers treatment in the javascript tests? I tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Due to the limitation imposed by [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), try to stick to the following rules:

**Rule #1:**

Avoid using `toNumber()` on any value returned from a contract function whose return-value type is one of the following:

- `uint64`
- `uint128`
- `uint256`

This also applies for public variables (since the compiler generates implicit getter functions for them).

**Rule #2:**

Keep the returned value in its original type (`BigNumber` on Truffle 4.x / web3 0.x, and `BN` on Truffle 5.x / web3 1.x), and use only the functions of this type (e.g., `plus`, `minus`, `mul`, `div`, `equals`, etc).

**Rule #3:**

For printout, you're best off using `toFixed()`, in order to avoid precision-loss as a result of scientific notation (e.g., `123.456e78`).

Please note that rule #1 also applies for on-chain functions which return an `address` value (which is converted to `string` at the off-chain side).

Comment: Thanks a lot @goodvibration! I'll try your suggestions and give the feedback!

Comment: Feedback: problem solved using chai-bn with bn.js! I was using toNumber(), hence there was the intrinsic limit of 53 bits. Thank you @goodvibration !

Comment: Note to future readers: use `toFixed()` for `BigNumber` (Truffle 4.x / web3 0.x) and `toString()` for `BN` (Truffle 5.x / web3 1.x).

Comment: I tried toString() n BN and got the same error `Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits`

Answer (score 7):

To do this in pure chai, you can use these two approaches:

```
const expected = web3.utils.toBN('123.052');
const actual = await meta.getBalance.call(account_two);
expect(actual).to.eql(expected); // compare to BigNumber
```

or use strings:

```
const actual = (await meta.getBalance.call(account_two)).toString();
expect(actual).to.equal('123.052');
```

Note that you have to use `eql()` (deep equality) instead of `equal()` when comparing BigNumbers or you'll get confusing errors like `BN<1> is not equal to BN<1>`.

Comment: no, you shouldn't use .to.eql otherwise you'll get something like ` AssertionError: expected '1000000000000000000' to deeply equal <BN: de0b6b3a7640000>
`

Answer (score 3):

As goodvibration mentioned, please avoid casting BigNumbers to js numbers. You can assert BigNumnbers using [chai-bignumnber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-bignumber), as follows.

```
(await contract.functionRetuningInt()).should.be.bignumber.equal(mixed_value);
```

Even better, [openzeppeling-test-helpers](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers/) can make your testing life a lot easier, specially for checking balance difference. Here's an example for [their docs](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers#balance):

```
(await balance.difference(receiver, () =>
  send.ether(sender, receiver, ether('1')))
).should.be.bignumber.equal(ether('1'));
```

Comment: With truffle v5 we have bn.js instead of bignumber.js, hence I solved the problem with chai-bn. Thank you