# Error : Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

Hi I am trying to run the following tests

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

var Bet = artifacts.require("./contracts/Bet");

const betAmountInEth = "0.25";
const wrongBetAmountInEth = "0.15";
const agreedUponBetAmount = web3.utils.toWei(betAmountInEth, "ether");
const wrongBetAmount = web3.utils.toWei(wrongBetAmountInEth, "ether");

contract("Bet", function(accounts) {
  const betOriginator = accounts[0];
  const betTaker = accounts[1];
  const badActor = accounts[2];
  const originatorBet = 4;
  const takerBet = 5;

  const originatorBalanceBeforeBet = web3.eth.getBalance(betOriginator);
  const takerBalanceBeforeBet = web3.eth.getBalance(betTaker);

  let bet;

  it("We should be able to start a bet by setting a guess and sending the bet amount that the contract was initialized with", async function() {
    const tx = await bet.createBet(originatorBet, {
      from: betOriginator,
      value: agreedUponBetAmount
    });
    expect(tx).to.exist;

    const betEvent = tx.logs[0].args;
    expect(betEvent).to.exist;
    expect(betEvent.gameStatus.toNumber()).to.equal(1);
    expect(betEvent.originatorStatus.toNumber()).to.equal(4);
    expect(betEvent.originatorAddress).to.not.equal(
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    );
    expect(betEvent.originatorGuess.toNumber()).to.equal(0); //Hides until the end
    expect(betEvent.takerAddress).to.equal(
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    );
    expect(betEvent.takerStatus.toNumber()).to.equal(0);
    expect(betEvent.takerGuess.toNumber()).to.equal(0);
    expect(betEvent.betAmount.toNumber()).to.equal(Number(agreedUponBetAmount));
    expect(betEvent.actualNumber.toNumber()).to.equal(0);
    expect(betEvent.pot.toNumber()).to.equal(0);
  });
```

Here are the events emitted during the test

```
 Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

Bet.BetStatus(
  gameStatus: Bet.GameStatusEnum.STATUS_STARTED (type: enum Bet.GameStatusEnum),
  originatorStatus: Bet.BetStatusEnum.STATUS_PENDING (type: enum Bet.BetStatusEnum),
  originatorAddress: 0x5cA881342Ab93763Fd2a8D66AE72A2554276590d (type: address),
  originatorGuess: 0 (type: uint256),
  takerAddress: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
  takerStatus: Bet.BetStatusEnum.STATUS_UNKNOWN (type: enum Bet.BetStatusEnum),
  takerGuess: 0 (type: uint256),
  betAmount: 250000000000000000 (type: uint256),
  actualNumber: 0 (type: uint256),
  pot: 0 (type: uint256)
)


---------------------------
2) We should be able to take a bet by setting a guess and sending the bet amount that the contract was initialized with

Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

Bet.BetStatus(
  gameStatus: Bet.GameStatusEnum.STATUS_COMPLETE (type: enum Bet.GameStatusEnum),
  originatorStatus: Bet.BetStatusEnum.STATUS_LOSE (type: enum Bet.BetStatusEnum),
  originatorAddress: 0x5cA881342Ab93763Fd2a8D66AE72A2554276590d (type: address),
  originatorGuess: 4 (type: uint256),
  takerAddress: 0xaD5A36fBEB78252d61d325E800b5085eA33645d7 (type: address),
  takerStatus: Bet.BetStatusEnum.STATUS_WINNER (type: enum Bet.BetStatusEnum),
  takerGuess: 5 (type: uint256),
  betAmount: 250000000000000000 (type: uint256),
  actualNumber: 7 (type: uint256),
  pot: 500000000000000000 (type: uint256)
)
```

The errors I am encountering:

```
1) Contract: Bet
       We should be able to start a bet by setting a guess and sending the bet amount that the contract was initialized with:
     Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
      at assert (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\bn.js\lib\bn.js:6:1)
      at BN.toNumber (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\bn.js\lib\bn.js:506:1)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\testBet.js:70:31)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

  2) Contract: Bet
       We should be able to take a bet by setting a guess and sending the bet amount that the contract was initialized with:
     Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
      at assert (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\bn.js\lib\bn.js:6:1)
      at BN.toNumber (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\bn.js\lib\bn.js:506:1)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\testBet.js:95:31)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I have found examples of people running into similar issues online and a workaround suggested was to downgrade truffle to v4 but ideally, I would like to keep truffle v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't downgrade to Truffle 4.x if you're already on Truffle 5.x.

The former simply ignores that issue, so it would be like sticking your head in the sand.

The value of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is indeed 53 bits (2^53 - 1).

So you should get rid of all the `toNumber` conversions in your code.

For more details how to use big numbers in truffle tests, see [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/67094/16043).

Proper disclosure - it was written by me.