# Truffle Test: Simply comparing BigNumber to String works, but WHY?

Tags: truffle, testing

Reading from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/67094/22522) post, one should not use `toNumber()` when working with `uint256`, so when writting the below test, I was expecting it to crash, but it does not, instead it runs to success! why ?

```js
  it("lottery amount should reflect previous two entries", async () => {
    const result = await contract.totalAmount();
    assert.equal(result, web3.utils.toWei("0.2")); // why we can compare BigNumber to string?
  });
```

`web3.utils.toWei("0.2")` is string, where `result` is BigNumber. So how can we simply compare them in an assert?

Comment: On Truffle 5.x, both are `BN` objects as far as I know.

Comment: @goodvibration I used `typeof` to check, `web3.utils.toWei("0.2")` evaluates to string

Answer (score 1):

From the Web3 [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-utils.html#id77):

> Returns
>
> String|BN: If a string is given it returns a number string, otherwise
> a BN.js instance.

You've passed in a string; you are being returned a string.

Hence you're comparing a string with a string.

Comment: `typeof web3.utils.toWei("0.2")` gives `String`, whereas `typeof result` gives `object`. So I am not sure how I am comparing a String to String, hence this question in the first place

Comment: Okay, but in the question you said `result` was a string. What is the value of `result`?

Comment: My bad, i had swapped the types around in the question. Fixed. result is a BN, whose 'toString()' evaluates to a string, ".2" ether in wei